# Understanding page 141 of Blundell’s Concepts in thermal physics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, adiabatic

On this page (in the second edition), there is a figure containing two states A and B of a system:

[image: Blundell p141]

There are two paths between A and B: one is an irreversible change, and the other is a reversible change. However, on the same page it says that entropy stays the same for a reversible change, and that entropy increases for an irreversible change. The first seems to imply that the entropy of A and B are the same; and the latter seems to imply that the entropy of B is larger than the entropy of A. This is a contradiction.

Am I missing something, or is this a mistake in the book?

Comment: The entropy of the universe increases on the irreversible path. But the final entropy of the system must be the same in both cases

Comment: "However, on the same page it says that entropy stays the same for a reversible change, and that entropy increases for an irreversible change."  The entropy of WHAT stays the same or increases.? Did it specifically refer to the entropy the system? Or were they referring to the total entropy, i .e., the entropy of the  system plus entropy of the surroundings?

Comment: I've downloaded a pdf file of Blundell. I can't find an edition number on it. In your copy, what is the figure number you are referring to.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this post unless you respond to my request for additional information.

Comment: @BobD if Riemann is, say, in Europe, your question about the figure was posted around midnight CET.

Comment: I am in Europe indeed

Comment: The remark about entropy staying the same for a reversible change, is on the bottom of the page, which is not on the pdf. There, they are indeed speaking about a thermally isolated system.

Comment: @Quillo since the necessary information has been provided I have withdrawn my close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on the same page it says that entropy stays the same for a reversible change,

yes, it says that

> and that entropy increases for an irreversible change

yes, it says that

> and the latter seems to imply that the entropy of B is larger than the entropy of A.

No, this does not follow from what the authors say.

They say that the heat along the reversible path and the the heat along the irreversible path satisfy the Clausius equation:
$$\int_A^B \frac{dQ}{T} \leq \int_A^B \frac{dQ_\text{rev}}{T} \tag{14.7}$$ It then says that since $dS = dQ_\text{rev}/{T}$ we must have
$$dS = \frac{dQ_\text{rev}}{T} \geq \frac{dQ}{T} \tag{14.8}$$
It follows that for an adiabatic process ($dQ=0$) we must have
$$dS \geq 0 \tag{14.9}$$
which is a statement of the second law.

The result does *not* imply that $\Delta S_{A,B}$ along the irreversible path is larger  than $\Delta S_{AB}$ along the reversible path, if by $\Delta S$ we are referring to the entropy change of the *system*. The statement would be correct if we are referring to the entropy change of the *universe*.

Comment: use $\delta$ instead of $d$ for heat

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the integrals are not loop integrals?

Comment: @Riemann You're right about the integrals -- edited.

Answer (score 2):

They might be referring to an **adiabatic** change, in which case, for a reversible path, the entropy change is zero.  If B is the final state for an adiabatic reversible change, there is no adiabatic irreversible path starting at A for which B can be the final state.  However, if the irreversible path is not adiabatic, the entropy of B can be the same as that for the reversible path.  In the latter case, the overall entropy change of the system is the result of both entropy exchange with the surroundings plus entropy generated within the system.

In general, for a non-adiabatic reversible change of thermodynamic state, the change in entropy of the system does not have to be zero.  And, for all changes between the same two thermodynamic equilibrium states (A tp B), whether reversible or irreversible, the change in entropy is the same.